# Wordpress update_post_meta caching old value

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to update a wordpress meta field and then display that new value once a form has been successfully submitted.

The field is actually getting updated but it seems like Wordpress is caching the old value when the page is reloaded.

Here's my code...

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_GET['pid'])) 
        header('Location: ' . get_bloginfo('wpurl'));

    $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'vacancies', 'p' => $_GET['pid']));
    $meta  = get_post_meta($_GET['pid']);
    $date  = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $meta['closing-date'][0]);

    if (isset($_POST['closing-date']) && $_POST['closing-date'] != '' ) 
    {
        if ($_POST['confirmation'] == $confirmation)
        {
            $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['closing-date']);
            update_post_meta($_GET['pid'], 'closing-date', $dt->format('Y-m-d'));
            echo 'Success';
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo 'There was an error';
        }
    } 
?>

<form method="post" action="http://<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>">
    <input name="closing-date" type="text" value="<?php echo $date->format('d/m/Y') ?>" class="datepicker form-control" />
    <input name="confirmation" type="text" class="form-control" />
    <input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_14" class="button button-secondary" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Can anyone tell me what's happening and how I can clear it? I've tried resetting the WP_Query object but that didn't seem to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try add

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```

after finishing updates and then make a new WP_Query to fetch new data

[WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: where you use the new data , the code you entered just for update
, i want to know where u fetch the data after updating it

Comment: Unless I'm just totally missing something...the form gets submitted to the same page which then makes the 'new WP_Query' to grab the data? Is that not right?